# What is more secure $_POST or $_SESSION?

Tags: php, jquery, security

I'm using the great [jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) image uploader, but need to store images for different users in subfolders.  I can do this either by sending the name of the folder as a `$_POST` arg to upload.class.php or retrieve the name as a `$_SESSION` arg.

Is there a preference for security?

Comment: What is tastier, apples or oranges? Really, the two *variables* are entirely different beasts used for different purposes. Are you basically asking whether to transport values between different pages using sessions or hidden forms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the folder name is to be inputted by the user, it should be in a `$_POST` variable with an appropriate form.

If it is a variable to be determined by the server, per user, it should be a `$_SESSION` variable.

There's no question of security here, there's a question of which is more appropriate for the required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use $_SESSION propogated from a DB user row.

$_POST must go over the wire where as $_SESSION does not. Also $_POST is directly modifiable from the form so a user can manipulate your form to upload to directory that is not theirs, this would not be good.

The main problem with $_POST comes from it's source, the HTML form which must be sent client side first.

Comment: Aren't session variables stored in cookies?

Comment: @Archer Generally only the session ID is communicated in some way (usually using a cookie, though there are other techniques), and everything related to the session is stored on the server, and just looked up using that ID.

Answer (score 0):

The most valuable concerns would be in how you use you variables (f.ex. preventing injections).

The two have very different persistences, also. You must choose whether you want a variable to be persistent session-wise ($_SESSION) or for only the particular page/script.